# Monitor Network Traffic of a Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking

Hello there good people of SE.

I have a small question regarding my network traffic on my Raspberry Pi I have at home.
The Pi main purpose is to host two servers. One TiddlyWiki Server and one Apache server with some self-hosted scripts. Other active services are the MariaDB and VNC

I've noticed, using `nload` that there is a **constant** OUTGOING traffic of about 9-10kb/sec and I would like to know exactly what is causing it. I've checked my Apache logs, which are rather normal.

Is there some way to know exactly which service is generating this constant traffic?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried shutting each one down one by one to see when the traffic stops?

Comment: Hello @DaddytheRunner. Thank you for your comment. Yes I've tried stopping all services such as apache, mysql, vnc, etc. but the network traffic persists. Is there any tool/application to view exactly what is causing this traffic?

Answer (score 3):

You can use nethogs to trace what the originating application making the connection is.

To install:

```
  sudo apt-get install nethogs
```

Root access needed to nethogs:

```
 sudo nethogs
```

To monitor multiple interfaces:

```
 sudo nethogs eth0 eth1
```